# sudo - /etc/sudoers is world writable on Ubuntu OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, sudoers

By mistake I change the permission of /etc/sudoers file on Ubuntu OS, now when applying any command using sudo, its  giving error,

- sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
- sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
- sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

I searched on goggle & getting many solutions but none worked in my case.

As I have **linux remote OS** server & I could not configure it by starting it & changing while boot up process as many people are giving solution for that.

Even **pkexec command** is also asking for password through which user I logged in to my server but I haven't password.
I am connecting to remote server using **.pem** file through SSH command. I used,

**pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers**, but it isn't worked as asked for password.

I am not able to apply any command such as, chown,chmod to alter permission as it is run only through sudo & sudo command isn't working.

Please let me know how to get rid out of this....

Please reply.
I will be grateful to you.

Thank you.

Comment: See related questions to the left — the first one seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: "related questions to the left" must be from stackoverflow.com, nothing to left here & related don't look helpful yet... So just a guess: log in as root?

Comment: and if is root not allowed as login, but you have the root-password - you can change to root with su-

Comment: yes I tried to login using su-- command but its giving permission denied error. I am working on Amazon Ec2 instance & I am not having idea about it.